# lldb xcode 8.1 enum symbol printing deprecated?

Tags: xcode, debugging, enums, lldb

With a typedef enum like

```
typedef enum
{
    black = 0,
    darkGray,
    lightGray,
    white,
    gray,
    red,
    green,
    blue,
    cyan,
    gold,
    magenta,
    orange,
    purple,
    brown,
    maroon,
    turquoise,
    lime,
    pink,
    yellow
} color_ndx_t;
```

it used to print enum symbols but no more; ie.

```
(lldb) p slip.slot.foreRGB
(color_ndx_t) $1 = 5
```

this used to print 'red'; using the newer format NS_ENUM() macro is no fix:

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger,color_ndx_t)
{
...
    pink,
    yellow
};
```

but still no enum symbols print anymore.  I keep such enums in a central include file used throughout my projects.  What am I missing?

Comment: I tried your example in a trivial project, and lldb always prints the enum name for me.  I can't reproduce your problem, so it's probably something a little trickier than just not printing enum names.

Comment: It's a swag but, perhaps some pref setting? Using Version 8.2.1 (8C1002)

Comment: I tried this debugging lldb, a moderately complex project, and I'm still seeing my enums (same tools version.)  I can't think of a setting that would affect this - debug information is pretty much on or off...  Sadly, I'm going to have to see an example to figure out what's up.

Comment: btw; I was migrating to 8.2.1 from 7.3.1 but kept older renamed; maybe that had an impact? I'd removed both (drag to trash) but unlike earlier version there is no longer a prior version cleanup step. Maybe there is something left over issue?  Anyway, after emptying trash and re-install, still no joy.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I resorted to rebuilding my project file. Not a trivial task but it works again. Did give me the opportunity to reorganize things but there has to be an easier way?